# Making a text field mandatory using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a student form with some input fields.Details like Name , Age should be entered.If the age of the student is less than 18 , parent details needs to be entered mandatory.

So in this case , i am checking the age of the student .If the age is less than 18 , i will shifting the focus to the parent text field.

The real trick here is i don't want the field to be empty.So until a value is entered ,the focus should be on the parent text field and cannot be changed.

How to achieve this ?

```
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input id="name" type="text" name="name" />
<label for="age">Age</label>
<input id="age" type="text" name="age" onblur="myFunction()"/>
<label for="parent">Parent</label>
<input id="parent" type="text" name="parent" />
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jegadeesb/tz6zybja/1/)

Any suggestions and ideas are welcome..

Comment: I would hate it. Anything at all that prevents normal navigation of a web page is irritating, and will alienate users. Imagine this scenario: I mistakenly enter age `11`; the focus moves to the parent field; I try to fix and put `21` in but I cannot get back into the age field. Horrible, horrible user experience. Let users edit as they will, give them red flags if the current state is not what you want and prevent submit, by all means; but don't mess with focus.

Comment: disable the other fields except the age and the parent fields

Comment: @Amadan Thanks for your reply.Same feeling here.Practically i would prevent the user at submit level.But the requirement has been such.Can you elaborate on how to achieve you suggestion..

Comment: Listen for `keyup`, `cut` and `paste` on the critical fields, check value in the handler, set `badEntry` class on the offending element that will give it red background if it is not what you want. Listen for `submit` and deny if any `badEntry` elements are found. Check everything again on the server since client can't be trusted.

Comment: With smart managers/clients, requirements can be changed. With stupid ones... the solutions below are pretty good.

Comment: @Amadan Haha exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/robinat130/225d1wy1/1/)
I hope this is what you are looking for,

```
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input id="name" type="text" name="name" onblur="checkage()" />
<label for="age">Age</label>
<input id="age" type="text" name="age" onblur="myFunction()"/>
<label for="parent">parent</label>
<input id="parent" type="text" name="parent" />


var age;
function myFunction() {
    age = document.getElementById("age").value;
    if(age < 18)
        document.getElementById('parent').focus();
}

function checkage(){
 var parent = document.getElementById('parent').value;
 if(age < 18 && parent == '')
     document.getElementById('parent').focus();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for something like this:

```
var x = document.getElementById("age").value;
if (x < 18) 
{
   if (document.getElementById("parent").value == "") 
   {
      alert('Parent detail is mandatory');
      document.getElementById('parent').focus();
      return;
   }
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5xm347gt/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution: https://jsfiddle.net/gwcgrn1s/1/

```
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input id="name" type="text" name="name" />
<label for="age">Age</label>
<input id="age" type="text" name="age" onblur="myFunction()"/>
<label for="parent">parent</label>
<input id="parent" type="text" name="parent" onblur="ValidationFunction()" />


function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("age").value;
    if (x <18)
    {
        document.getElementById("parent").focus();
    }    
}

function ValidationFunction()
{
    var parentName = document.getElementById("parent").value.trim();

    if (parentName.length == 0)
    {
        document.getElementById("parent").focus();
    }
}
```